# Html Text Box Pattern Validation

Tags: html, validation, textbox

I am learning HTML and I have one problem. I have text boxes, and in the text boxes I want to type only characters, no special characters.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate() {
if (document.myForm.name.value == "") {
    alert("Enter a name");
    document.myForm.name.focus();
    return false;
}
if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(document.myForm.name.value)) {
    alert("Invalid characters");
    document.myForm.name.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

You Can Use following Script to Validate your text box..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an input field that only allows A-Z, a-z character values.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Country Code">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```